# What is the major difference between blender 2.79 and 2.8?

Tags: versions

The blender has gone through major UI changes in newer version of blender i.e. version 2.8.
But what are the major technical updates it got?

Comment: Hello :). It's all summed up in the [release notes for Blender 2.8](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80)

Comment: I think Eevee and Collections are the major differences